# Vercel Deploy "Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations."

Tags: typescript, vercel

I have a project, which uses package that contains only ts interfaces useful for my project. But when I deploy my project to Vercel I get

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@goskan93/trello-clone-contracts' or its corresponding type declarations.
  > 1 | import { UserInput, AuthOutput } from '@goskan93/trello-clone-contracts';
```

I understand the nature of this error, but I cannot find where I use incorrect case, for me looks like I don't do any mistake with this.

This is my package with contracts https://github.com/goskan93/trello-clone-contracts/tree/main

here is the usage https://github.com/goskan93/mobx-trello/pull/10/files